# Can InnerHTML in JavaScript hold PHP Variable or Mysql query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to send with innerhtml a PHP and Mysql query , Is that possible? .
and I want it to be done just with innerHTML and JavaScript .

```
<?php
echo '<script>
function ()
{...
document.getElementById("drawrequest").innerHTML="$com="select * from market";
...}
</script>';
?>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot I want to change about this but I'll hit the basics:

**First**: Swap your single quotes ( ' ' ) with the double quotes ( " " ).  Single gives a literal response (meaning `$that` will output literally *$that* instead of the variable).  [Refer to this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) for further explanation if needed.

**Second**:  Your code is backwards.  The less parsing your PHP has to do the better off you'll be (and more likely to pass without error).  Instead of echoing that whole Javascript, just type that outside of your `<?php ?>` tags and then echo with those tags as needed (like your MySQL query).

**Third**:  I don't see any actual MySQL query that would do anything here.  I have to assume you've already established connection but that code isn't going anywhere.  I'm assuming you meant this:

```
$com = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM market', $conn);
echo "...innerHTML = '$com';";
```

I shortened it between echo and innerHTML to save time.  I also will leave the re-arranging to you as it's your decision.

Cheers

Comment: tnanks for this Tips .

Comment: mysql code is long so i put one order in as an example .. but infact you can't swap single quotes because PHP will not print html tags without them .. :_(
so i need a way to make innerhtml print html tags without effecting on PHP variable that i need to use them with my html tags .
as Example :
innerhtml='if($..){echo '<select ...>'};';

Comment: its not too in depth but im barely staying awake as it is.  We'll pick this up tomorrow though.  At least reverse the position of your code so it's an actual JS file with PHP placed as needed.